# Get file id to get file from item - Podio API

Tags: podio

So I wanna get the file from my item and save it to my server but I cant seem to get file id from item. How do I do it? When I view the item details via PodioItem:get the file details i only get are:

```
 [files] => Array
                (
                    [type] => File
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                            [json_value] => file_id
                            [json_target] => file_ids
                        )

            )
```

I wanna know how to get the file id of the item then i am planning to use the `PodioFile::get_raw( $file_id );` code to get the file

I would really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

You can get an item by using the API

```
 $item = PodioItem::get($itemID);
```

Also, you can get the files attached to an item by using $item->files

```
 if ($item->files && count($item->files) > 0) {
        foreach ($item->files as $fileID) {
            $file = PodioFile::get($fileID);
            $fileRaw = $file->get_raw();
            // save the file 
            file_put_contents($yourPathToSaveFile, $fileRaw);// make sure you have permission to save the file to the location
        }
    }
```